# Linking emails to calendar appointments

Tags: calendar, iphone

I have an iPhone 4S. I schedule all my appointments through the iPhone calendar app. Typically I receive an email with all the pertinent information  and in turn, I have to transfer all of the information from the email to the calendar. When the appointment comes around, I have to search through my email files in order to locate any additional information. Is there a way to link emails to the calendar in order to easily access them when my appointment date comes up?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link the emails and iCal events, however you can create the event by tapping on the date within the e-mail. You can then double tab on the content of the email, select all, and the copy and paste into the notes section of the iCal event.

Answer (score 1):

if you drag and drop an email (without a date) from mail into calendar it WILL contain a link back to the email

Comment: Seems like your answer is not intended for the iPhone (drag and drop?). Any clarity you can add for the iPhone 4s in this question would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward the email to yourself and write a date ( like tomorrow at 16). In the received email this will be blue colour (tomorrow at 16) and you can create event directly from email.
What is good? In calendar at that event you will (on URL) you will find Show the message in Mail and will open that email with attach and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this. It's quite a bit hacking but you are able to link most mails to your calendar via deeplinking with iOS 7 or higher.

What you need to do:

1. First thing you need to do is to figure out the Message-ID of an email. This message ID is enough to get you to the desired mail

Unfortunately, you cannot get message-ID on the iOS (AFAIK, maybe you could do some hacking with Shortcuts as for now...) So you need to get the message-ID elsewhere (GMAIL, MAIL.APP on mac or Outlook)

in Mail.app you need to go to

**Mail -> Preferences -> Viewing -> Show Message headers -> Custom...**

After this you will see table where you need to fill just **Message-ID**

After this, you will be able to see the Message-ID in your UI, basically under the default information in the header UI.

2. Copy this message ID and create somewhere in notes the deeplink -> `message:a69de646a026e501c5557d738387f00f@mlsend.com` (your ID will be different, this is just some ID of codewars email which was sent to me xD)
3. Paste this whole deeplink (`message:Message-ID`) into URL textfield of calendar event and create it.
4. ???
5. Profit